# Different URLs for the same link

Tags: asp.net, url, web

I have a news article which opens up with two different URLs when accessed from different places on the site. An example would be:

1.)http://www.test.co.se/News-Article/Your%20invitation%20to%20the%20big%20birthday%20bash%20tomorrow%C3%A9e/253

2.) http://www.test.co.se/News-Article/Your-invitation-to-the-big-birthday-bash-tomorrowC3%A9e/253

In the original link, there is the character **é**

Is that the reason? If not what is it?

Comment: How are these URLs generated? Server side or client side? Somehow the `-` was replaced with `[space]` in the first URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both urls are same the difference is 1st is encoded

URLs can only be sent over the Internet using the ASCII character-set.

Since URLs often contains characters outside the ASCII set, the URL has to be converted. URL encoding converts the URL into a valid ASCII format.

URL encoding replaces unsafe ASCII characters with "%" followed by two hexadecimal digits corresponding to the character values in the ISO-8859-1 character-set.

URLs cannot contain spaces. URL encoding normally replaces a space with a + sign.

[You can read more here:](http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/urlEncoding/)

Comment: `'%20'` means space, not `'-'`. So it is not the same URL.